# ios Sprite Kit - How to add a smaller view with close button for example for settings

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene, skview

I want give user the possibility to change some option. So if one touch on a "button" element build by touchevents and SKLableNode, I want to open a smaller modal view with close and other buttons. Has anyone an Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Yup, add a node to the scene that contains whatever you need for the menu. Extra view is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Any Node? You mean, SkSpriteNode with an panel image, contains "button" etc.? Sure? It's possible to give any examples? Cheers

Comment: Yup, nodes are your "view" hierarchy within Sprite Kit. No need for an example, add a sprite with a frame image, then add a sprite with a button image and a label to it, and position them. That should give you a good start and you'll see where this is going. ;)